# Why are localhost requests to an Apache virtual host running locally so slow?

Tags: performance, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have my Windows 7 localhost server configured with my main localhost address and a couple of virtual hosts configured to serve cookie-less images and JavaScript (I also have a few other virtual hosts configured).

I am having 5000ms load times on a couple of the files using the virtual host address and could use some help figuring out why.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Based upon the advice on [this post](http://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2010/07/fixing-slow-apache-on-localhost-under.html), I've commented out `::1 localhost`. I'll see if this solves the problem and report back.

My hosts file contains the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost static mseifert design static-mseifert static-design
::1 localhost
```

My virtual hosts are set us as so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin michael@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/mseifert/xyz"
    ServerName static

    <Directory "D:/Website/mseifert/xyz">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        Allow from localhost
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin michael@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Website/mseifert"
    ServerName static-mseifert

    <Directory "D:/Website/mseifert">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
        Allow from localhost
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

There are no errors in my apache access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:38:49 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 101841
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /css/colwidth.min.css?v=1476516603 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /js-common/dragdrop.min.js?v=1483776115 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /css/slideshow.css.php?static-img-common=http://static-mseifert/img-common&v=1484865716 HTTP/1.1" 200 6394
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /css/slideshow.min.js?v=1486279758 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /js-common/common.min.js?v=1485074534 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /js/media.match.min.js?v=1370658510 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /css/ms.min.js?v=1485063063 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /css/wtr.css.min.php?static-img-common=http://static-mseifert/img-common&static-site-root=http://static&static-top-root=http://static-mseifert&v=1486360034 HTTP/1.1" 200 37255
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:11 -0800] "GET /js/hmac-sha1.js?v=1455443904 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img-common/lock.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img/lady.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img/lady-header.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img-common/menublank.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img-common/menublanka.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img-common/arrow.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Feb/2017:20:39:12 -0800] "GET /img-common/vmenuback.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Only use IP addresses in Apache config directives.

Instead of using `localhost` in your Apache config file, just use `127.0.0.1`. So this:

```
Allow from localhost
```

Changes to this:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I go into more detail in [my other answer to another question over here](https://superuser.com/a/972962/167207), but basically `HostnameLookups` is a slow process for Apache and when it is part of an Apache config directive, `HostnameLookups` switches on **even if it is disabled elsewhere**. So it trues to resolve `localhost` and just hangs and hangs.

This cleared up many “mystery” hangs on Apache servers that used `Allow`/`Deny` directives.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Commenting out ::1 localhost seemed to take care of it on first blush, but the sample size was small.

Comment: Having commented out ::1 localhost seemed to solve the problem and the 5000ms times went away. Interestingly, when changing all `Allow from localhost` to `Allow from 127.0.0.1` in the httpd-vhosts.conf (there are none in httpd.conf), the performance monitor again shows many files with 5000ms load times.