# DNS resolution delay for entries in /etc/hosts

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, dns, hosts-file

For the purposes of doing web development, I have several domain names specified in my `/etc/hosts`. These represent several different websites that are being run locally.

```
127.0.0.1    site1.local
127.0.0.1    site2.local
127.0.0.1    site3.local
```

This works fine, but I'm seeing a 5 second delay in loading pages from any of these domains. Browser developer tools attribute this delay to DNS, and it's always exactly 5 seconds.

Curiously, this also only happens in Chrome and in Firefox. Safari has no delay at all.

I thought that perhaps the browser is querying the normal DNS servers before falling back to the hosts file. Doing a DNS query with `dig site1.local` returns no results (as you would expect), but also returns results very quickly (17ms), so that doesn't seem to be the case.

What is causing the 5 second delay in looking up hosts in the `/etc/hosts` file, and how do I reduce or eliminate this delay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Slow to Resolve /etc/hosts on macOS / OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/1189379/chrome-slow-to-resolve-etc-hosts-on-macos-os-x)

Comment: Have you tried using another browser such as FireFox? Are you using Apache for your local development setup? If so, disable `HostnameLookups` in your `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache is slower on other computers on local area network than on localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/807134/apache-is-slower-on-other-computers-on-local-area-network-than-on-localhost)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke They mention they use Firefox as well. So I believe this is not a Chrome specific issue or specific to any browser. I believe this is a networking issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 If it's a network issue you would expect it to happen in Safari as well, right? The question I linked to links to a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10064581/1256347) which does not mention a browser. However, [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806345/1256347) mentions a resolution that commenters say fixed a very similar issue to that of OP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The 5 second delay when visiting hostnames ending with `.local` is due to Bonjour, and explained [in this answer about a different issue on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17982964/242552).

I was able to use the workaround suggested in that answer and add an IPv6 entry for each server and avoid the 5 second delay. It's unclear why adding both an IPv4 and IPv6 entry causes Bonjour to be avoided, but it does work.

```
127.0.0.1    site1.local
127.0.0.1    site2.local
127.0.0.1    site3.local
::1    site1.local
::1    site2.local
::1    site3.local
```

Comment: Excellent solution!

Comment: For me, it was a 9.99 second (10 second) delay in Chrome. Fingers crossed that this works!

Answer (score 1):

#### If you are using Apache, Apache is is most likely hanging on DNS lookups for your local development site hostnames.

> “I thought that perhaps the browser is querying the normal DNS servers before falling back to the hosts file. Doing a DNS query with `dig site1.local` returns no results (as you would expect), but also returns results very quickly (17ms), so that doesn't seem to be the case.”

This all sounds like a networking issue to me and the delay seems to be a DNS lookup related issue. Apache is trying to resolve the hostnames for `site1.local`, `site2.local` and `site3.local` and is hanging due to the DNS lookup for those hostnames failing. Then when Apache finally gives up — and gets to the `/etc/hosts/` file, the site finally loads.

I go into more detail in [my other answer to another question over here](https://superuser.com/a/972962/167207), but basically `HostnameLookups` is a slow process for Apache and when it is part of an Apache config directive, `HostnameLookups` switches on **even if it is disabled elsewhere**. So it trues to resolve `localhost` and just hangs and hangs.

This cleared up many “mystery” hangs on Apache servers that used `Allow`/`Deny` directives.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not using Apache at all.

Comment: @leecbaker Then what are you using as a web server?

Comment: Most of of the servers are Flask, with a couple of one-off other things. An `nginx` proxy routes forwards requests to the various servers, all running on different ports.

Comment: @leecbaker Ahhh… Makes sense. Happy you found a solution, but I would also recommend looking up how to disable hostname resolution in Nginx and even Flask. The reality is hostname lookups for webservers are typically used for logging purposes. So the only functionality you ever lose by disabling it is having hostnames resolved in logs.